# pyttsx.init() not working in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-to-speech

i tried to use the python 2.7 library pyttsx on windows, pip installation was fine but when i try

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
```

it breaks and gives an error. importing doesn't give an error, but the pyttsx.init() does.
I'm using windows if anyone can fix it or knows another text to speech python library that would be great :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, it's fine...
it works perfectly